# IBM JSON Parser error

Tags: json, mfp

I am working IBM MFP8 security check adapter. Once user authenticated, my backend service will give user data in JSONObject and storing that user data in attribute as a string. In another adapter i was calling this user data and trying to parse again to JSONObject and getting bellow error while parsing string to JSONObject.  Please help to identify where the issues and how can i fix this issue.

Code:

```
import com.ibm.json.java.JSON;
import com.ibm.json.java.JSONArray;
import com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject;

AuthenticatedUser user = securityContext.getAuthenticatedUser();            
String queryParams = (String) user.getAttributes().get("queryParams");
JSONObject queryParamsObject = (JSONObject) JSON.parse(queryParams);
```

Error:

```
    [err] org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.ibm.json.java.internal.Parser.parse()Lcom/ibm/json/java/JSONObject;" the class loader (instance of com/ibm/mfp/server/core/shared/ParentLastClassLoader) of the current class, com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject, and the class loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ParentLastClassLoader) for the method's defining class, com/ibm/json/java/internal/Parser, have different Class objects for the type com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject used in the signature
    [err]   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:163)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    [err]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
    [err]   at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox$3.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:579)
    [err]   at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:86)
    [err]   at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:584)
    [err]   at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.rest.AdaptersEndpoint.adapterServing(AdaptersEndpoint.java:115)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    [err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    [err] Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.ibm.json.java.internal.Parser.parse()Lcom/ibm/json/java/JSONObject;" the class loader (instance of com/ibm/mfp/server/core/shared/ParentLastClassLoader) of the current class, com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject, and the class loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ParentLastClassLoader) for the method's defining class, com/ibm/json/java/internal/Parser, have different Class objects for the type com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject used in the signature
    [err]   at com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject.parse(JSONObject.java:79)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
```

Comment: sounds like a library mismatch

Comment: Yes paul. I removed below dependency from pom and working fine now

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

Thanks